# A generic error occurred in GDI+ while converting dataimage string to image

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to save image date to physical file

Below is image data which I got from a jpeg image (via some browser response):

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgEASABIAAD/.....blah blah .....//2Q==
```

Below is the code I am using to save image data string to Image

```
Image image = LoadImage(dataURL);
image.Save(saveLocation);
image.Dispose();

public Image LoadImage(string imageString)
{
    imageString = imageString.Substring(imageString.IndexOf(',') + 1);
    byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(imageString);

    Image image;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    {
        image = Image.FromStream(ms);
    }

    return image;
}
```

Getting the following exception at `image.Save(saveLocation);` line

> A generic error occurred in GDI+.

I have no issues when the image source with png images with the same code but with jpeg images no matter what the size of jpeg is I am getting that exception every time.

I am able to save the png images with same code at same location.

Edit: Please note that I am getting just data image string from browser (which I am capturing via clipboard of browser) i.e I am not getting bytes from client.

Is there any limit for the bytes which can be converted to image stream and then save back to physical file?

Is there any other approach to do the same?

Comment: Why don't you save it as is? write the bytes to a file and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be any reason to go through `Image` at all here.

Assuming the posted data is valid, just write the content to a file directly:

```
SaveImage(dataURL, saveLocation);

public bool SaveImage(string imageString, string location)
{
    try {
        imageString = imageString.Substring(imageString.IndexOf(',') + 1);
        byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(imageString);

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(location, FileMode.Create))
        {
            fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Count);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```